# python: print numbers like product of two natural numbers

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

Sorry noob here.
I would like to have a function which, for a given natural number, will printout all possible pairs of 2 natural numbers whose product makes the input.

I think it could be like this, but still can't figured out how to write it properly:

(the last output line is missing in my code output)

```
def print_products(n):
    for i in range(1, n):
        if n % i == 0:
            print(n, "=", i, "*", int((n/i)))
```

And output should be like this:

```
print(print_products(36))

36 = 1 * 36
36 = 2 * 18
36 = 3 * 12
36 = 4 * 9
36 = 6 * 6
36 = 9 * 4
36 = 12 * 3
36 = 18 * 2
36 = 36 * 1
```

Thanks for the help and possible explanation

Comment: [`range`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#typesseq-range) stops at, but does not include, `n`

Comment: Use `range(1, n+1)`, see if it works as you intend.

Comment: This is a simple off-by-one-error. Your for loop is stopping one short. Just add one to your upper range bound like others have said

Comment: Is there a reason you'ved tagged this question with both `python-3.x` and `python2.7`?

Comment: @Lurker in Python 3, `print` is a function. Indeed, if one is writing new Python 2 code one should import and use this function fro. `__future__` . To be fair, OP tagged this *both* 2 and 3...

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga sorry, yes, I am running Python 2.7.12. I don't use it that much lately, so wasn't paying attention to the version.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `range()` function does not include the end (stop) value so `i` is never actually `n`. This is easy to correct with a `+1`. You should also use integer division (`//`) as it is neater than passing a `float` into `int()`.

Making your function:

```
def print_products(n):
    for i in range(1, n+1):
        if n % i == 0:
            print(n, "=", i, "*", n//i)
```

and it now works:

```
36 = 1 * 36
36 = 2 * 18
36 = 3 * 12
36 = 4 * 9
36 = 6 * 6
36 = 9 * 4
36 = 12 * 3
36 = 18 * 2
36 = 36 * 1
```

---

We can see from the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#range) that `range()` does not include the `stop` parameter:

> For a positive step, the contents of a range `r` are determined by the formula `r[i] = start + step*i` where `i >= 0` and `r[i] < stop`.

The proper terminology is to say that `i` *does not **attain*** the upper bound (`stop`).

Comment: wow, that was fast, thanks a lot. 

Comment: @Hrabě Please accept (grey --> green tick) to show your appreciation! Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Just use `n+1` in the range function:

```
def print_products(n):
    for i in range(1, n + 1):
        if n % i == 0:
            print(n, "=", i, "*", (n/i))
```